# How to interpret logarithmically transformed coefficients in negative binomial regression?

Tags: regression, data-transformation, negative-binomial-distribution

How can I interpret log-transformed independent variables in terms of percent change in a negative binomial regression?

Comment: Using what link function?

Comment: @Glen_b: Let's say it's the log link.

Comment: @Brash in that case, in much the same way you'd interpret it in a log-log regression (with the additional twist that it's percentage change in counts). I guess I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Interpretation depends on the link function.

i) if the (typical) log-link is used then the coefficients relate log-change in y to log-change in x, and so the interpretation would be the same as for a log-log regression -- roughly speaking they represent "percentage change in y for a 1% change in x" (as long as the coefficient isn't large). However, on the link scale, we wouldn't be talk about the coefficient giving *expected* percentage change.

ii) if some other link is used, some other interpretation would be needed -- but again, the interpretation is again similar to in the regression case; for example, an identity link would yield a similar coefficient-interpretation as for an ordinary regression where $x$ is logged but $y$ is not.